# How can I migrate data from one redis cluster to another redis cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

We are running redis clusters inside 2 different kubernetes cluster.

We would like to migrate data from Old redis cluster to new redis cluster without any downtime.

Both redis cluster are exposed thru service (ClusterIP) and pods from one k8s cannot communicate with pods running in another k8s cluster. Both can communicate over service IP.

Is there any tool or strategy that we can use to migrate redis cluster form old k8s to new k8s without any downtime or with minimal downtime.

Any help will be appreciated.